# ORM EntitySave() - ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When attempting to do an `EntitySave("publications",arguments);` .. I receive the following error.

```
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): publications
```

I can't work out why.. My database primary keys are set up correctly, and I have setter=false these properties in my CFC.  I have found a bit on this error doing a Google search, but nothing seems to indicate what is causing my issue here.

Here are my CFC's.  Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong are appreciated.  Thanks heaps in advance!

Publications.cfc

```
component persistent="true" table="publications"  
hint="Publications"{
    property name="id" fieldtype="id" setter="false";
    property name="typeid" omrtype="int";
    property name="name" ormtype="string";
    property name="dateScheduled" ormtype="date" ;
    property name="tstamp" ormtype="date";

    property name="Article" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="publicationArticles" fkcolumn="publicationid";
}
```

publicationArticles.cfc

```
component persistent="true" table="publicationArticles"  
hint="Publications"{
    property name="id" fieldtype="id" setter="false"   ;
    property name="typeid" ormtype="int";
    property name="title" ormtype="string" ;
    property name="status" ormtype="boolean";

    property name="publication" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="publications" fkcolumn="publicationid" ;
}
```

publicationTypes.cfc

```
   component persistent="true" table="publicationTypes"    
hint="Publicatin Type - Lookup"{

    property name="id" fieldtype="id" setter="false"   ;
    property name="description" ormtype="string";

    property name="publications" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="publications" fkcolumn="typeid" ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a generator property to it? I've never tried mapping a primary key without a generator. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSB7BEC0B4-8096-498d-8F9B-77C88878AC6C.html#WSA1F7CC44-F5A0-419c-B988-EC230EFF192E

Comment: s992, you are my hero! setting generator="identity" did the trick.  I have the database managing the primary key generation, so figured I didn't need to do anything with this in the Entity.  Clearly we do.  I could have also gone generator="native" (which worked as well), but going by the link you sent 'identity' seems the better option.  If you could repost as an answer I'll happily flag as such.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a generator on the property.

```
property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
```